# C# returning error “not all code paths return a value” - how to find the path not returning a value

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am very new to programming in general so I may be missing something very obvious. But still, which path leads to not returning a value?

```
public static int CheckAge()
        {
            int userAge; 
            bool inValidInput = true;
            while (inValidInput)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
                string stringAge = Console.ReadLine();

                if (int.TryParse(stringAge, out userAge))
                {
                    switch (userAge)
                    {
                        case int n when (n < 1 || n > 120):
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.Write("RANGE ");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            Console.Write("error\n");
                            Console.Write("Accepted range are numbers (eg. 123) ");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            Console.Write("between 1 and 120\n");
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                            break;

                        default:
                        return userAge;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    Console.Write("TYPE ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("error\n");
                    Console.Write("Accepted input types are ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    Console.Write("numbers (eg. 123) ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("between 1 and 120\n");
                    continue;  
                }
            }
        }
```

When I look at it I feel like all paths should EVENTUALLY lead to:

```
default:
   return userAge;
```

If I need to provide the full source code please let me know and I will add it, did not want to make it to messy in case all I needed was the example.

**EDIT:**
I really liked the solution given by @oerkelens but I am struggling to make the userAge variable behave properly. **Below** Using:(return userAge; inside if statement):

```
public static int CheckAge()
        {
            int userAge;
            bool inputIsValid = false;
            while (!inputIsValid)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
                string stringAge = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(stringAge, out userAge))
                {
                    WriteNumericalError();
                    continue;
                }

                if (userAge < 1 || userAge > 120)
                {
                    WriteRangeError();
                    continue;
                }

                inputIsValid = true;
                return userAge;
            }
        }
```

Gives me the good old: 'Program.CheckAge()': not all code paths return a value

**Below** Using:(return userAge; outside if statement):

```
public static int CheckAge()
        {
            int userAge;
            bool inputIsValid = false;
            while (!inputIsValid)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
                string stringAge = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(stringAge, out userAge))
                {
                    WriteNumericalError();
                    continue;
                }

                if (userAge < 1 || userAge > 120)
                {
                    WriteRangeError();
                    continue;
                }

                inputIsValid = true;
            }
            return userAge;
        }
```

Solved the 'Program.CheckAge()': not all code paths return a value but introduces: Use of unassigned local variable 'userAge'

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
public static int CheckAge()
        {
            int userAge = 0;
            bool validInput = false;
            while (!validInput)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
                string stringAge = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(stringAge, out userAge))
                {
                    WriteNumericalError();
                    continue;
                }

                if (userAge < 1 || userAge > 120)
                {
                    WriteRangeError();
                    continue;
                }
                validInput = true;
            }
            return userAge;
        }


        private static void WriteNumericalError()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.Write("TYPE ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("error\n");
            Console.Write("Accepted input types are numbers ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.Write("(eg. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0)\n");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to try again");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void WriteRangeError()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("RANGE ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("error\n");
            Console.Write("Your entered number does not fall within the accepted range ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("1 to 5 for film choice - 1 to 120 for age input\n");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to try again");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: The first case in the if has a `break` so the `return userAge;` will not be reached if `(n < 1 || n > 120)` is true.

Comment: The compiler is not smart enough to realize that you're code is either an infinite loop or it eventually returns, so you need a return at the end after the `while` loop.  You also don't need the `continue` at the end of the `else`, it will continue to loop by default

Comment: I must have misunderstood completely when return is needed. I thought that since no path leads to leaving the method until return userValue it would not argue that any path does not return a value.. 
So I can not use it like this? To "force" it to run until I get a (for the purposes that i want it to be) valid value and return only that?

Comment: If you write `while (true) { ... }`, the compiler knows that the loop will never terminate on its own. If you write `bool condition = true; while (condition) { ... }`, the compiler can't work out that the loop will never terminate. You never set `inValidInput` anyway, so just get rid of it and use `while (true)`

Comment: The compiler seems to notice the infinitly loop only if you write `while(true) {..}`

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I am new to stackoverflow so I am not sure how I mark my question as solved since afaik no answer has been provided? Can i submit an answer myself based on the feedback from you guys and choose that as the answer?

Comment: Simply change `int userAge;` to `int useAge = 0;` to get rid of the new warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're using an obscured infinite loop. Even as `while (true)`, this seems like a code smell.
Secondly, your flag has a negative meaning. That drives people mad. `inValidInput == false` means the input is valid!
Third, it's hard to see what you want to accomplish with your code.

Below is an example addressing these things. There are still other possible improvements, but it's a start.

```
public static int CheckAge()
{
    int userAge = 0; 
    bool inputIsValid = false;
    while (!inputIsValid)
    {
       Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
       string stringAge = Console.ReadLine();

       if (!int.TryParse(stringAge, out userAge))
       {
           WriteNumericalError();
           Continue;
       }
       
       if (userAge < 1 || userAge > 120) 
       {
           WriteRangeError();
           Continue;
       }

       inputIsValid = true;
   }
   return userAge;
}

private void WriteNumericalError()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("RANGE ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("error\n");
    Console.Write("Accepted range are numbers (eg. 123) ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("between 1 and 120\n");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
private void WriteRangeError()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    Console.Write("TYPE ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("error\n");
    Console.Write("Accepted input types are ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    Console.Write("numbers (eg. 123) ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write("between 1 and 120\n");
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Thank you for the constructive feedback covering more general grievances as well. Much appreciated!

Comment: I did however get some errors trying to compile this solution: 
1) An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.WriteRangeError()'
2) same for WriteRange
3) Use of unassigned local variable 'userAge'
Surely I did something wrong, but in case I didn't, did you miss something?

Comment: I fixed the object reference by making the members I called static as well (any reason this is bad in my example?) I also fixed the variable issue by moving it within the if statement scope.

Comment: Just make both methods static

Comment: I am still struggling with the userAge variable.. Moving it inside of the if statement scope made it assign the value to it but it also made the method not see a return value after the if scope which made it complain again. if I assign a random number to it and return it as is where it originally was, will it ever reach it if I moved the original return after inputIsValid = True ?

Comment: The return should be _outside_ the while loop. And assigning a value of 0 to the variable solves your warning. The loop is only exited if the user has given a valid input, and that input is in the variable that you return.

Comment: @oerkelens Thank you so much! I really liked your solution so was a bit bummed out that i could not get it to work properly. I did actually assign a value as you eventually suggested but since I am very new to programming I was not confident that i did not introduce some unintended behavior. Your explanation here really made a difference for me to understand why it was okay. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a `switch` statement the `default` is only hit if no `break` point is hit before. In your code, if your first case is met it won't return anything if `(n < 1 || n > 120)` evaluates to `true`.

Typically you use `break` to exit the switch statement and ensure only one case is triggered but in your case you want the case to trigger and the default trigger so you should remove the `break`.

However, I'd suggest that based on what you currently have a switch statement is less efficient and unnecessarily complicated for what you're doing.

You might try something like this:

```cs
public static int CheckAge()
{
    int userAge;

    //while (true) is required to indicate infinite loop and clear the code paths error
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
        string stringAge = Console.ReadLine();

        if (int.TryParse(stringAge, out userAge))
        {
            if (userAge < 1 || userAge > 120)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("RANGE ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("error\n");
                Console.Write("Accepted range are numbers (eg. 123) ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("between 1 and 120\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
            else
            {
                return userAge;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.Write("TYPE ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("error\n");
            Console.Write("Accepted input types are ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.Write("numbers (eg. 123) ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("between 1 and 120\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not get @oerkelens solution to work (see my EDIT in original post) so I implemented this solution instead mixed in with some of his suggestions.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @iluvpancakes see my edit and my comment. simply assign a default value to your int and it's fixed.

Comment: @iluvpancakes I'm glad this works for you, but I'd encourage you to think about your design a bit more because a `while (true)` loop is rarely an ideal approach.

Comment: @WSC Thanks for the feedback, Oerkelens explained how to make his solution work so now I can adopt a while(true)-less design and think carefully about using it in the future if I come across a similar situation. Thanks for the valuable feedback!

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, the compiler yelled at me saying "not all code paths return a value".  I made the two changes commented below and it worked fine for me at that point.

```
public static int CheckAge()
{
    int userAge = 0; //I added =0 to appease the compiler warnings
    bool inValidInput = true;
    while (inValidInput)
    {
         //your existing code   
    }
    return userAge;  //added this to appease the compiler
}
```